# Why doesn't require work for database credentials?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function that connects to database. The function will work if I hard code the database credentials. But if I use a require or include with database credentials it will not work and I get connection error. I can echo the credentials from the include and require file from the function though.

```
class mysql{

    function verifyUser($un,$pwd){
        include 'cat.inc.php';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db) or die("This is an error connecting".mysql_error());

        $sql = 'select salt,pwd,hospital_id, fname,lname,client_id,employee from client where email = ?';

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

            $stmt->bind_param('s', $un);
            $stmt->bind_result($salt,$storedPwd,$hospital_id,$fname, $lname,$client_id,$employee);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->fetch();

            if (sha1($pwd.$salt)==$storedPwd){

                $_SESSION['clientID'] = $client_id;
                $_SESSION['hospitalID'] =$hospital_id;
                $_SESSION['client_fn'] = $fname;
                $_SESSION['client_ln']=$lname;
                $_SESSION['employee']=$employee;    
                $_SESSION['start']=time();  
                return true;

                }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You're mixing database API's and that really will not work very well, if at all.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I will read the information that was provided in the comments and return with my results.